# Border radius effect with IE9 and a solid border

Tags: css

I just noticed that my address link styled as a button does not properly show a radius in IE9 when using the CSS below:

```
a.btn {
    background: #F00;
    color:#333;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    border:1px solid #444;
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    cursor:default;
}
```

[CSS example](http://jsfiddle.net/6Nr2n/)

When I remove the border:1px solid #444; then a nice curved border appears.

Is this a bug with IE? In Firefox everything works good. Anyone else seen anything like this? Seems like it only happens when border-radius is set to a low value. I know this is not very important on the scale of things but I'm interested to hear if anyone knows why the radius doesn't properly show.

Comment: May I suggest accepting the answer that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
Check it using

```
border-radius: 20px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Nr2n/1/

http://prntscr.com/2djxa

Comment: Yes it works for larger radius. But I wonder why not for smaller. Seems like IE behaves differently from the other browsers.

Comment: Yeah maybe just the way IE renders compared with the other browsers. When I remove the solid border it works better. Perhaps MS needs to work on it's graphics algorithms ...